# Mysql trigger error host server

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have written a trigger as described below using phpmyadmin assistant , the result looks right , when I export the SQL code and insert it into a MySQL host server, these errors occurs.

```html
CREATE TRIGGER `occupy_trig` AFTER INSERT ON `sgr_customer`
    FOR EACH ROW begin
    If(New.company != "")THEN
        Insert into sgr_customer_group (id_customer, id_group)VALUES(NEW.id_customer,4);
    END IF;
        
END
```

[image: Mysql errors]

What's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set a different DELIMITER. There are plenty of examples on the [TRIGGERS PAGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) in the mysql documentation.

Comment: yes ,     DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER occupy_trig AFTER INSERT ON sgr_customer 
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF(New.company != "")THEN
Insert into sgr_customer_group (id_customer, id_group)VALUES(NEW.id_customer,4);
END IF;
 END; //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: but nothing is done , no new row is inserted , what issue could exist  either on localhost it works fine

Comment: when i try  with static values it works DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER occupy_trig AFTER INSERT ON sgr_customer 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO sgr_customer_group(id_customer, id_group)VALUES(1234, 4);

 END; //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: we get  New.id_customer  with select ?